# Как работать с iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, php

Доброго всем времени суток.
Т.к. `js` на прямую не может работать с БД (`MySQL`), я начал искать способы взаимодействия. Погуглил разные темы и нашел схему `js <--> iframe с php`. 
Но почему то не удается наладить связь с `iframe`.

Создав `iframe` невидимый на основной страничке, со скрытыми полями `< input id="h1" type="hidden" >`, хочу заполнить их с помощью `js`. Ну и по логике PHP код обработает запрос и заполнит эти поля данными, которые я js считаю обратно и заполню поля на страничке.

Подскажите варианты или как решить этим способом данный вопрос. Желательно с примерами. Я много "гуглил" тем, по этому вопросу и варианты типа `"window.frames["hiddeniframe"].h1.value"` - к сожалению не работают, почему не знаю.

Где тут @ зарыта? как заполнить поля в `iframe` и потом прочитать их `value`.

Comment: м, может посмотреть в сторону ajax?

Comment: Я бы советовал для взаимодействия js+mysql+php использовать JSON и быстро, и легко

Comment: @FrancNet

     js на прямую не может работать с БД (MySQL

Слишком сильное утверждение. См., например, https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не `iframe` нужен, а простая `html` форма:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" value="Alex" />
<input type="hidden" name="surname" value="familia" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

На стороне сервера принимаете ваши поля в `php`:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo $_POST['username']. " ". $_POST['surname'];
}
```

Обратите внимание на то, что `javascript` - это язык, который работает на стороне клиента, он может взаимодействовать с серверными данными через запросы, напр. через `ajax`. Как по мне `iframe`'ы и вообще фреймы лучше не использовать на сайтах.

Скорее всего вы с запросами `$_GET` и `$_POST` не можете разобраться.

Comment: Я делаю типа редактирование записей из БД, ну и для заполнения полей мне нужно отправить запрос в БД и полученными данными заполнить поля для дальнейшего редактирования или использования. На моей форме редактирования есть кнопки типа "назад" "вперед" для считывания записей из БД.

по $_POST мне все понятно, я принимаю на сервере запрос из формы, обрабатываю его а как послать данные обратно так чтобы поля заполнились не могу придумать. Вот и решил воспользоваться вариантом "обмен через скрытые поля", но не получается.

Если есть более доступный метод то очень буду признателен

Comment: ну это уже через `javascript` тогда, у ваших полей обязательно должны быть или имена или идентификаторы, вам как раз `jQuery` бы не помешал, у него есть методы `ajax` и `post`, посмотрите их.